# Eloquent and Pivot Tables in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, pivot-table, eloquent

I have a Poll table, a Students table, and a pivot table between them that includes a token and their three votes.

```
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'polls_students')->withPivot('token','first','second','third');
    }
```

While working out saving the poll results, I came across some odd behavior that I don't quite understand.  I'm hoping somebody can explain what it is I'm missing:

```
    $poll = Poll::find(Input::get('poll_id'));

    foreach($poll->students()->where('students.id', '=', Input::get('student_id'))->get() as $student){
        var_dump($student->pivot->token);
    }

    $student = $poll->students()->where('students.id', '=', Input::get('student_id'))->get();
    var_dump($student->pivot->token);
```

In the above code, the `foreach` loop will successfully display the token, where the second one throws the exception `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$pivot`

What am I missing?  Are these two calls not logically creating the same object?  How is 'pivot' working on the first and not the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You first example:

```
$poll = Poll::find(Input::get('poll_id'));
foreach($poll->students()->where('students.id', '=', Input::get('student_id'))->get() as $student){
    var_dump($student->pivot->token);
}
```

Here `$poll->students()` retrieves a collection and because of `foreach` loop you get a single object in your `$student` variable and you can use `$student->pivot->token`

### You second example:

```
$student = $poll->students()->where('students.id', '=', Input::get('student_id'))->get();
var_dump($student->pivot->token);
```

Here you are doing same thing, using `$poll->students()` you are getting a collection but this time you are not using a loop and trying to do same thing using `$student->pivot->token` but it's not working because you didn't define any index from which you want to get the `pivot->token`, if you try something like this

```
$student->first()->pivot->token
```

Or maybe

```
$student->get(1)->pivot->token
```

Or maybe you can use `first()` instead of `get()` like this

```
$student = $poll->students()->where('students.id', '=', Input::get('student_id'))->first();
```

Then you can use

```
$student->pivot->token
```

Remember that, `get()` returns a collection even if there is only one record/model.

Comment: Thank you. Having the same problem (second example) in Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0):

```
$poll = Poll::find(Input::get('poll_id'));

foreach($poll->students as $student){

    var_dump($student->pivot->where('student_id',$student->id)->where('poll_id',$poll->id)->first()->token);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) While it's great that you included code in your answer, it would be even better if you included an explanation of how and why your code works. You can use the edit button under your post to update it.